# How to fix the error "Use of Unresolved identifier" when actually I can access that identifier

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, sirikit

I have a class which is defined as a Singleton and I try to access 2 functions from that class but I get an error which is saying that class can't be found but when I press Cmd + Click I'm able to navigate to that class.
I restarted xCode so many times, also I tried with xCode 10 and xCode 9...the same error. I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
// First Class
class BankAccount {

    private init() {}

    static let bankAccountKey = "Bank Account"
    static let suiteName = "group.com.YourName"

    // Function to set the balance for ShoppingLand Bank
    static func setBalance(toAmount amount: Double) {
        guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: suiteName) else { return }
        defaults.set(amount, forKey: bankAccountKey)
        defaults.synchronize()
    }

    // Function to check new updates about the balance of ShoppingLand Bank
    static func checkBalance() -> Double? {
        guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: suiteName) else { return nil }
        defaults.synchronize()
        let balance = defaults.double(forKey: bankAccountKey)
        return balance
    }

    @discardableResult
    static func withdraw(amount: Double) -> Double? {
        guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: suiteName) else { return nil }
        let balance = defaults.double(forKey: bankAccountKey)
        let newBalance = balance - amount
        setBalance(toAmount: newBalance)
        return newBalance
    }

    @discardableResult
    static func deposit(amount: Double) -> Double? {
        guard let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: suiteName) else { return nil }
        let balance = defaults.double(forKey: bankAccountKey)
        let newBalance = balance + amount
        setBalance(toAmount: newBalance)
        return newBalance
    }
}

// Second Class

import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension {}

extension IntentHandler: INSendPaymentIntentHandling {
    func handle(intent: INSendPaymentIntent, completion: @escaping (INSendPaymentIntentResponse) -> Void) {

        guard let amount = intent.currencyAmount?.amount?.doubleValue else {
            completion(INSendPaymentIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil))
            return
        }

        BankAccount.withdraw(amount: amount)
        completion(INSendPaymentIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil))
    }
}


extension IntentHandler: INRequestPaymentIntentHandling {
    func handle(intent: INRequestPaymentIntent, completion: @escaping (INRequestPaymentIntentResponse) -> Void) {

        guard let amount = intent.currencyAmount?.amount?.doubleValue else {
            completion(INRequestPaymentIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil))
            return
        }
        BankAccount.deposit(amount: amount)
        completion(INRequestPaymentIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil))

    }
}
```

Here is a demo:

http://recordit.co/NoXKlT3dw1

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Please point out which line(s) are giving you errors.

Comment: Please click the Demo to see what is the error. Is saying that class BankAccount can't be found.

Comment: I'm not clicking some strange link. You need to update your question to clearly indicate which line(s) are causing errors.

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'BankAccount'. This is the error. But when I press Cmd+Click on BankAccount is navigating to the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your class file of BankAccount is available for your other target -> ShoppingLandSiri. you can check it from the file inspector view.

Comment: This is it baby ! Back in business ! Thank you so so so much !

Answer (score -1):

You haven't set up your singleton correctly. `BankAccount` is a class, not an instance. A singleton is a version of a class where only one instance will be accessed, but you're still accessing an instance. You need to add:

```
class BankAccount {
    static let shared = BankAccount()
    ...
```

to your BankAccount class. The `shared` property is the actual singleton instance. Later on when you're trying to access the singleton, instead of

```
BankAccount.withdraw(amount: amount)
```

you want to use that instance:

```
BankAccount.shared.withdraw(amount: amount)
```

Comment: You're getting the same error on that withdraw line?